# Using Safecracker with Playa

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker, playa

I'm using Safecracker to edit entries for the Channel Books. Suppose I have another Channel Publications.

I am using a Playa field to create relationships.

My understanding is that you can only use Playa to create relationships between existing entries. Is there a way to create a Publication entry and at the same create a relationship to the Book entry we are editing / creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playa can only be used to create relationships between entries that actually exist in the EE database.

Comment: Hmmm that is what I suspected. I think I will end up going with this solution:
Use Safecracker to create a form for adding a Publication (if it doesn't already exist).
Then upon successful insertion of this Publication data into the database I'll have to perform some SQL query to create this relationship correctly.

Any advice on doing this? I was going to use the `safecracker_submit_entry_end` hook

Comment: Best to start on this code, then ask specific questions when you hit walls or post as a new question for direction.